# Please help on this matrix transformation problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, transformation

Let A be the matrix below and define a transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ by $T(U) = AU.$ For each of the vectors $B$ below, find a vector $U$ such that $T$ maps $U$ to $B$, if possible. Otherwise state that there is no such $U$.
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & -3& 2 \\
        2& -4& 4 \\
        3& -8& 6\\
        \end{pmatrix} =A
$$

a)$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        4\\
        6\\
        11\\
        \end{pmatrix} =B
$$
b)$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        -3\\
        -2\\
        -7\\
        \end{pmatrix} =B
$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you share your thoughts and what you have tried? Regards

Comment: Well, I tried to find the inverse of A but that didn't work, I don't think I understand this enough to do it correctly.

Comment: The reason you found no inverse is because $A$ is not invertible. This can be seen by showing that $\det A=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: write $U=(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ and then work out $AU$ in terms of these components. You now have a system of linear equations to solve in the form $AU=B$.